# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: стилистика

"Состояние коммуникаций в любом поселке требует профессиональных навыков".

Может ли состояние требовать чего-то? Или опорное слово "коммуникаций"?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, опорным здесь является словосочетание "состояние коммуникаций"

Comment: Тогда правильно сформулирована фраза?

Comment: В ответе на похожий Ваш вопрос я предложил изменить фразу

Comment: Удовлетворительное состояние коммуникаций в любом посёлке зависит от наличия профессиональных навыков у слесарей ремонтных бригад. Исходная фраза весьма аляповата.

Comment: Или похожий вариант: "Для обеспечения удовлетворительного состояния коммуникаций в любом поселке требуется наличие профессиональных навыков у рабочих ремонтных бригад". Исходная фраза не просто аляповата, а ошибочна.

Comment: Или похожий вариант: "Для обеспечения удовлетворительного состояния коммуникаций в любом поселке требуется наличие профессиональных навыков у рабочих ремонтных бригад". Исходная фраза не просто аляповата, а ошибочна.